# How to loop through a combox values list and select one of them

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, combobox

How do I cycle through a ComboBox Values list so I can check each value and select one of them efficiently?

Examples in C# or VB.Net welcome.

Comment: A ComboBox has only one "value".  Are you talking about the Items property?  Have to used foreach to iterate it?  An item in Items is of type object so use ToString().

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "Winforms:" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To cycle through combobox values, you can use the Items property. If combobox values are strings, the VB code would look like this:

```vb
For each item As String in myComboBox.Items
  'Do something
Next
```

To select a value, you can use the SelectedItem property:

```vb
myComboBox.SelectedItem = "SomeValueInComboBox"
```

Comment: Make sure to break out of the loop once you have selected the value that you want. (no point looping through data you don't need)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var item in comboBox1.Items)
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
```